# Is $L = \{a^n b^m b^m \mid n,m \ge 0 \}$ regular language or not regular language?

Tags: regular-language

> Is $L = \{a^n b^m b^m \mid n,m \ge 0 \}$ regular language or not regular language?

I think that $L$ is regular because the regular expression `a*(bb)*` describes this language. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct